# Tell Espresso to run specific tests on an emulator

Tags: android, junit, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I have Android instrumentation tests with Espresso.  Some of my tests must be run on an emulator - due to using LinkedIn's TestButler (https://github.com/linkedin/test-butler) library.  This library toggles wifi/gsm for specific test runs, and that is why these tests must be run on an emulator.

My question is - can I annotate any specific tests to run on an emulator, while having the other tests run on a real device?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward solution I found is to use JUnit Assume API: http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assume.html

So, inside the test methods that can only be run on an emulator, I put this code:

```
Assume.assumeTrue("This test must be run in an emulator!", Build.PRODUCT.startsWith("sdk_google"));
```

This results in the said test being ignored when it isn't run on an emulator, and a handy error msg in the run window:
[image]

---

As you can see, the other two tests passed fine (in the green), and the entire test suite was able to run.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use a `@ConditionalIgnore` annotation as described in http://www.codeaffine.com/2013/11/18/a-junit-rule-to-conditionally-ignore-tests/.

You will have something like

```
public class SomeTest {
  @Rule
  public ConditionalIgnoreRule rule = new ConditionalIgnoreRule();

  @Test
  @ConditionalIgnore( condition = NotRunningOnEmulator.class )
  public void testSomething() {
    // ...
  }
}

public class NotRunningOnEmulator implements IgnoreCondition {
  public boolean isSatisfied() {
    return !Build.PRODUCT.startsWith("sdk_google");
  }
}
```

## EDIT

For this specific case of detecting a device or emulator you can also use `@RequiresDevice`.

Comment: What is the difference between this rule and the one from Apache: issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-167